# checking out project from svn access forbidden

Tags: java, svn

i want to check out a project from svn,but it gives an error(the server is actually runnig)

```
    URL access forbidden for unknown reason
     svn: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http:.................'
      svn: Access to '............' forbidden
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is with a wrong repository access path configuration in svn server.
For e.g. if you are trying to access repository path

**yoursvnserver.com/repo/projectRepository/trunk**

and svn repository access rules is set wrong as below you could face the mentioned error. Please check with your svn server admin to fix this.

```
[groups]
superUser=admin
projectDev=user1,user2

[projectRepository:trunk]
@projectDev=r

[projectRepository:/branches]
@projectDev=rw
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means that your user account does not have permissions to read the repository path you want to checkout. Contact your manager or server / repository admin for assistance with this issue.